# Band Structure of Graphene from Exact Diagonalization of Finite Lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, graphene

Say I write down a real space matrix Hamiltonian for a finite graphene lattice, perhaps a rectangle with N sites along each axis. Of course if I had an infinite lattice then I can use Bloch's theorem and calculate the bandstructure, giving the famous Dirac dispersion close to E = 0. Is there a way I can approximately reproduce this result using a finite lattice? The issue I'm running into is, I can diagonalize the Hamiltonian and get the eigenvalues, however I don't know how to relate these eigenvalues back to something that resembles a bandstructure (the eigenvalues don't have a $k_x$ or $k_y$ index).

Comment: You don't need an infinite lattice to use Bloch's theorem. It also works in the case of a finite lattice with periodic boundary conditions, and it is much simpler than working with a finite lattice without periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: @GiorgioP indeed, the whole point of Bloch’s theorem is that there are periodic boundary conditions. You need a large lattice if you’re simulating a non-periodic defect.

Comment: Yes, indeed you are right! But the essential point for Bloch's theorem is periodicity. Although the above system I'm mentioning does have periodicity if one extends it to an infinite lattice (or makes the boundaries periodic), I'm ultimately going to be adding on-site terms to the Hamiltonian which break periodicity. However, I was hoping I could recover something like the bandstructure of just normal finite graphene, before I've done the periodicity breaking.

Comment: You can get something that looks like a band structure for a finite lattice (even without boundary conditions), provided the lattice has enough sites. You’ll need to group the numerical eigenvalues by hand to get the different bands, but it will visually look like the band structure, discretized. Try it for a 1D lattice first for convenience to see what happens.

Comment: @march Could you give some detail or a reference on how to do this in the 1D case? After I compute the eigenvalues, it's not clear to me how to group them to get something looking like bandstructure.

Comment: How many sites did you use? How many orbitals on each site? Etc @Zonova

Comment: @march Say I use 1000 sites on an SSH model (ie a 2 site basis, where A->B hopping has a larger coefficient than B->A hopping). When I compute the eigenvalues, I have a line of lower eigenvalues, one eigenvalue at E = 0, and then a line of higher eigenvalues. I can see how this might "look" like a bandstructure in some sense. But that's only because this is a 1D problem and my eigenvalues are ordered in 1D. In 2D, I have no idea how to spread my list of eigenvalues along a 2D plane in an intelligent way.